# Why doesn't import work with intermediate variable?

Tags: javascript, webpack, dynamic-import

It looks impossible, but the code stops working if I put concatenation of first two parts to the variable. This works:

```
async findImage(code)
{
    const map = (value) => value.default;

    return await import('images/certification/' + code + '.svg').then(map);
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
async findImage(code)
{
    const map = (value) => value.default;

    let pathWithoutExtension = 'images/certification/' + code;

    return await import(pathWithoutExtension + '.svg').then(map);
}
```

It says "svg selected: Error: Cannot find module 'images/certification/eco_friendly.svg'" though this path is correct.
How can it be?

I call this function in another async function with await:

```
 image = await this.findImage(cert.code);
```

Comment: Can you run `return await import('images/certification/eco_friendly.svg').then(map);` successfully? My guess is that you'll still receive the same error (since the `code` variable is injecting into the string properly as we can see in the error message. Are you sure you're loading the correct relative path?

Comment: sure, I can, it works with this string @domdambrogia

Comment: Are you using Webpack? Webpack's dynamic import expression resolution is limited.

Comment: @AaronBeall yes, I use Webpack. What is meant by limitation?

Comment: @Audiophile That's a good question, it's not too well defined in my opinion. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4292#issuecomment-281870789

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4292#issuecomment-451034292